# Angular 1.2.5 animation classes are not removed in iOS6

Tags: javascript, angularjs, animation

I have an animation, where the box slides up and down. It works on web, ios and android phonegap app and mobile safari (All I tested). It also works on iPhone5 iOS6, but I have problems because supporting classes, such as ng-hide-add, ng-hide-remove are not deleted after the animation completes. Does anyone eperienced similar issues?

EDIT: it basically appears that animation doesn't work on iOS6. Classes are added, but never removed.

UPDATE: the issue seems to happen when the animation time is less then 0.5s

Answer (score 1):

I did some tests and it looks that something in my application caused animation classes on iOS6 to be sticky if the animation is under 0.5 seconds. I was able to solve the issue in a hacky way, by deleting the classes manually upon the animation complete event.

```
if(ios6) {
    $('.element').on('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend', function() {
        $('.element').removeClass("ng-animate ng-hide-add ng-animate-start ng-animate-active ng-hide-add-active ng-hide-remove ng-hide-remove-active");
    });
}
```

Comment: I think I am also having the same issue on android 4.1.2  (Galaxy s2 browser) , but it seams the trick you did didn't work for me , still fiddling around

Comment: You are right about the animation duration being the culprit.

Comment: The issue I had was that after animation completes, the overlay would still remain on the page with high z-index and it was causing unresponsiveness on iOS6. I delete classes, so it goes to pristine state.

Comment: I found my problem (but it is a bug on the webkit side). I had on the same page another animation that was set to 50 seconds(for debugging purposes). Setting it to what I intended 0.x seconds removed the problem.  I created plunkr with my directive that was having the problem 'br-gesture' (br  == my project name). The problem was not in this directive , it was on the other component that had 50+ seconds animation . Feel free to expand on it if you like it http://plnkr.co/edit/AAUgk2?p=info